# How to use an HTML minifier with underscore templates

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs, minimize, underscore.js-templating

I have some templates for my frontend code, like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="my-header col-md-1">
        <!-- comments -->
        {{ title }}
    </div>
    <div class="my-container col-md-11">
    {% if (content) { %}
        {{ content }}
    {% } else { %}
       <p>Empty</p> 
    {% } %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm using [grunt-contrib-jst](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jst) to store them all in a single file and then on another build step will be included in a single JS file and that file is pushed to the CDN. This part is working perfectly, but I want to use the `processContent` option to minify the HTML template code, which contains Undercore template delimiters (`<%...%>` replaced with `{% ... %}`, `<%= ... %>` replaced with `{{ ... }}`).

I wanted to use [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.org/package/html-minifier) but it doesn't actually minimize anything, apparently because it tries to parse the template as HTML-only (and fails because of the templating tags).

Is there any Node package / function that allows me to minimize this kind of templates? I would like to use comments and whitespace in source templates but strip everything unnecessary on the resulting build file.

Right now I have this on my JST settings:

```
processContent: function (content) {
    return content
        .replace(/^[\x20\t]+/mg, '')
        .replace(/[\x20\t]+$/mg, '')
        .replace(/^[\r\n]+/, '')
        .replace(/[\r\n]*$/, '\n');
},
...
```

But I want to minimize everything possible, that's why I tried with [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.org/package/html-minifier).

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I have the same problem where my JST size could be significantly reduced.

Comment: @JoshWLewis sorry, no luck yet :( Apparently this kind of minimizer has to be aware of the Underscore tags and minimize everything outside of those tags.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really help with minimising the underscore template delimiters, still trying to find out the best way to do that myself, but you might want to consider running your templates through [htmlclean](https://github.com/anseki/htmlclean). I use it with r.js and it works really well for stripping out newlines and spaces in the code. Example usage:

```
var htmlclean = require('htmlclean');

// ...
processContent: function (content) {
    return htmlclean(content)
        .replace(/^[\x20\t]+/mg, '')
        .replace(/[\x20\t]+$/mg, '')
        .replace(/^[\r\n]+/, '')
        .replace(/[\r\n]*$/, '\n');
},
```

I've had no problems with using this on HTML that has underscore templates in there. I hope it helps you.